# Reconnecting sockets in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

Here's the problem. I'm attempting to set up a very simple app that will send messages to a Java server.

Here is my server code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
Socket clientSocket =null;
try 
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    System.out.println("Server Started...");
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();            
}catch(Exception e){};

Scanner in = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String inputLine;

while (true) 
{
    if(in.hasNext())
    {                   
        inputLine=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Message from server: "+inputLine);
    }
}
```

And here's the client code:

```
Socket client;
PrintWriter printwriter;
String serverIpAddress="192.168.173.1";
Button button;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client = new Socket(serverIpAddress,4444);
                        printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                        printwriter.write("Start");
                        printwriter.flush();
                        //printwriter.close();
                        //client.close();                                   
                    }
                    catch(UnknownHostException e)
                    {

                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                           
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

I have one button, when I press it a message is sent to the server and it displays fine, but when I press the button the socket does not reconnect so I can't send the massage again.

To be clear I intend to eventually add more buttons to send different messages. I looked into creating a global socket but that didn't seem to go anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `while(true)` loop is poor form. It should be either `while (input.hasNextLine())`, removing the subsequent test, or, better still, lose the `Scanner` altogether and use a `BufferedReader` like so: `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null).` Your exception handling is atrocious. Never ignore an exception, and never put code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block outside that `try` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not closing the socket in the client code. You should close the streams & sockets in both server and client when the connection is over. Saying this, you should keep the connection alive and send several messages instead of closing the connection after sending one message.

I would  for example rewrite the server code as (please note that this handles only one client):

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket =null;
    Scanner in = null;
    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("Server Started...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        in = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String inputLine;

        while (true)  {
            if(in.hasNext()) {
                inputLine=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Message from server: "+inputLine);
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if(clientSocket != null) {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Just a note: I would use DataInputStream & DataOutputStream... in this way, you could use in.readUTF() in the server side which will block until receiving something new through network. In this way, you will not have to do while(true) which will be way much better for the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I did get it working.

Multithreader, thank you, you were completely correct about where my problem lay. I did it a bit differently though.

I set up another class to set up the socket and created a method to start listening on the given port. In the main I just put that in a loop to keep closing and recreating the socket till the end condition is met.

Thanks again all.